# DevExpress Object in Blazor with foreach loop

Tags: c#, blazor, devexpress

Code = Blazor Server

I have a SQL Table Roles with ID and RNames. The count isn't fixed.
I tried to create a DevExpress DxTagBox in a foreach loop. But my Problem is, the bind-value is in every loop object the same.
I tried with ChatGPT :-)
and I tried with index, but nothing works. Maybe someone here can help.

That's the code:

```
@foreach(var inputRoles in Roles)
{
    <div class="flRow">
        <DxTagBox Data="@User"
                  TextFieldName="@nameof(USER.USR_NAME)"
                  ValueFieldName="@nameof(USER.USR_NR)"
                  @bind-Values="@RolesID_New"
                  NullText="@inputRoles.InfoCard_Roles"
                  ClearButtonDisplayMode="DataEditorClearButtonDisplayMode.Auto">
            <DxListEditorColumn FieldName="@nameof(USER.VORNAME)" Caption="Vorname"/>
            <DxListEditorColumn FieldName="@nameof(USER.NAME)" Caption="Nachname"/>
        </DxTagBox>
        <p class="w-25">@inputRoles.RName</p>
    </div>
}
```

That's the part of RolesID_New down in @code
`IEnumerable<TBL_Roles> RolesID_new { get; set; }`

Comment: There is no direct connection.
In my Oninitialized I get all items from database in an IENumerable Users and in IENumerable Roles.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `ValueFieldName="@nameof(USER.USR_NR)"` Or change the list `RolesID_new` type to the same type of `USER.USR_NR`.